# Call Back in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to call the back button command at some point in my application programmatically, so what is the command for that.
The issue is that i need the application to exit when the user presses back from the second page, hence i need to call the back button command when navigated on to the first page to exit.
I searched online and found out that there is no systematic way to exit an application in code so any suggestion?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();` in `OnNavigatedTo` of the second page. This will remove the first page from the navigation stack and if the user presses the back key the application will exit.

Warning: Call remove only once! (multitasking calls `OnNavigatedTo` multiple times)

```
private bool removed = false;
public override void OnNavigatedTo(...)
{
    if (!removed) 
    {
        removed = true; 
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
```

(WP 7.1 [Mango] only)

Comment: Agreed - this should do what the OP needs, while not attempting to exit the application from code (which won't work), or resorting to exceptions (which will fail Marketplace testing).

Answer (score 1):

I found that this worked for me using Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (mango):

```
private bool removeBack = true;

private void PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress ( object sender , System . ComponentModel . CancelEventArgs e )
{
    if ( removeBack )
    {
        this . removeBack = false;

        if ( NavigationService . CanGoBack )
        {
            this . NavigationService . RemoveBackEntry ( );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

This can be called on a Page to go back again - if this is the first page your app will exit, you can't force an exit from an application - in 7.1 there are methods to remove pages from the Navigation "backstack" that can skip a page to achieve a similar effect such as:

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

However that does only work on "Mango" SDK and devices/emulator

---

Sorry this solution doesn't work have checked this, but am leaving this here incase it is useful to someone.

Comment: I tried this command, however i'm getting an exception since there is no entry exists in the back navigation so when this is the first page and this function is called the application doesn't exit, any reason why and thanks in advance.

Comment: Indeed you're correct - should have double checked, had read somewhere that worked - now I know it doesn't myself now. However it seems you can only exit via the hardware back button when on the First page - you could try having a ViewModel or just a Canvas with content for the first and second page so they are actually just MainPage.xaml that way navigating back will always exit, but I'm not sure this will behave in a way that will work for your situation